# Using a .bat file to start xampp if it is not yet started

Tags: php, batch-file

My problem is, I have a php system that I have developed for a small shop but the problem is that the users are not very much computer literate to start xampp everytime as my system runs on localhost.

I came up with this code for a batch file to start mozilla and get to the system folder in htdocs.

```
start firefox.exe http://localhost/systemname/
```

But my problem is if xampp is not started, the user meets a 404 error.

Can I use something like this (probably a php script)

```
if(batch xampp is not running){ start xamp & Mysql }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys I have found a solution

I created two vbs files to start http ans Mysql then created a .bat file to run both files and sleep for 30 seconds then start firefox to the htdocs\mysystem folder this is to give the servers enough time to start running.

Please ignore my quetion as my problem is ssolved if you encouter the same problem you may refer to this how-to